# How to read a file using delimiter and write in a different file line by line based on delimiter using shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a requirement, say file foo.txt which contains key-value pair like below:
vi foo.txt

```
a^1.0^b^2^cc^30^d^4^e^55^fg^67.0^h^8^i^99
```

and so on.
I have to write a shell script to put each key-value pair in different line to a different file, say goo.txt which contains:

```
a^1.0^
b^2^
cc^30^
D^4^
e^55^
fg^67.0^
h^8^
i^99^
```

I have a similar Perl script for it, but I want shell script. The Perl script is like

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
my $filename     = "";
my $Tags         = "";
GetOptions ('file=s' => \$filename);
if (defined $filename and $filename ne "")
{
    open (my $DATA,$filename) or die $!;
    $Tags       = <$DATA>;
    while ($Tags =~ m/(.*?\^.*?\^)/g)
    {
      print "$1\n";
    }
    close($DATA)
}
```

I want a similar code using shell script. Need help to write a shell script (ksh) for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`cat filename |  awk -F"^" '{split($0, a, "^"); for(i=1;i<NF;i=i+2){print a[i]"^"a[i+1]"^"}}`'

Comment: Code only answers are improved with some explanation. Also, it taking the time  to format your code would help

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I am looking for. It resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You want an extra newline after each second `^`.
The fields are without a `^`, A character not `^` can be written as `[^^]`.
Each two fields (any amount of letters excluding `^` followed by a `^` and again),
should be replaced by the match, followed by a newline.

```
sed 's/[^^]*^[^^]*^/&\n/g' foo.txt
```